# webkit transform rotate not working on Safari

Tags: css, sass, safari

Im trying to make the **rotation** of this CSS animation work on Safari.

```
@keyframes hexagon {
  0% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
  50% { transform:rotate(360deg); }
  68% { transform:rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1); }
  71% { transform:rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1); }
  76% { transform:rotate(360deg); transform:scale(1.25); }
  85% { transform:rotate(360deg); transform:scale(1); }
  86% { transform:rotate(360deg); transform:scale(1); }
  100% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
}
```

You can check it at https://codepen.io/bryceyork/pen/JdRbQw

I have added the webkit- prefix, but its still not working:

```
@-webkit-keyframes hexagon {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  68% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  71% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  76% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
            transform: scale(1.25);
  }
  85% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  86% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

You can check it at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoQGeL

What am I doing wrong? Should I add anything else?

Comment: You need to repeat the whole _@keyframes_ directive with and without _-webkit-_. You can also add autoprefixer in your bundle or codepen option.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have done it here but still not working... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMbayg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is vexing, but I think I sort of solved it by brute force. You may want to tweak timing. I didn't touch your original keyframes, but did change the webkit keyframes. Using a different-coded set of keyframes for webkit seems to do the thing you want:

```
@keyframes hexagon {
  0% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
  50% { transform:rotate(360deg); }
  68% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
  71% { transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1); }
  76% { transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1.25); }
  85% { transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1); }
  86% { transform:rotate(360deg); }
  100% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hexagon {
  0% { 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1); 
  }
  75% { 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);  
  }
  75.1% { 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1);  
  }
  80% { 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1); 
  }
  88% { 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1.25); 
  }
  96% { 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1); 
  }
  100% { 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }

}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWeYwL
You'll note in the codepen I also do this:

```
-webkit-animation: hexagon 3.5s ease infinite;
 animation: hexagon 4s ease-in-out
```

As to WHY this works... honestly I do not know. Feels like a bug. Not tested in IE!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check the code carefully

Answer (score 1):

You are overwritting your transforms properties.

If you want both transformations then separate them with a space.

Also don't forget to add prefixing for transform and keyframes. Vendor prefixes have to be placed before the orginal ones.

The whole code looks like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes hexagon {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  68% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
            transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  71% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
            transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  76% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
            transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
  }
  85% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
            transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
  86% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
            transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes hexagon {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  68% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
            transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  71% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
            transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  76% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
            transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
  }
  85% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
            transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
  86% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
            transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```